# could not execute update query error in hiberante query

Tags: hibernate

Iam writing the following code for delete in hibernate

Query query = session.createQuery("delete  Contact contact where contact.firstName  = 'Deepak'");

```
              int row = query.executeUpate();
              if (row == 0){
              System.out.println("Doesn't deleted any row!");
              }
              else{
              System.out.println("DeletedRow: " + row);
              }
```

It gave me the following error
Hibernate: delete from CONTACT contact0_ where (contact0_.FIRSTNAME='Deepak')
could not execute update query

Can anyone help me

Comment: can you post complete stack trace, this error is not descriptive.

Comment: Hibernate: delete from CONTACT contact0_ where (contact0_.FIRSTNAME='Deepak')
could not execute update query  this is what iam getting in my console

Comment: the query generated by hibernate is delete from CONTACT contact0_ where (contact0_.FIRSTNAME='Deepak') i would like to know is this correct since where clause is with in ()